# ActionScript 3 trying to clone google Halloween game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

This past Halloween Google put out a game that used drawn symbols to initiate a function. Using a mouse or drawing table, the game would recognize x, o, <, >,- or |... each enemy had one or more of these symbols above them and had a hierarchy from left to right. As you drew a symbol each enemy with it as their left most would suffer an attack.

1. Is this possible in actionscript 3? I can't find any resources to help
2. If it is how complicated can the symbols be?

Comment: First idea I've had is a mouseDown event producing movie clip at a set rate and and use a function to monitor their percession and changes. To recognizing different shapes by allocating a movie clip to manifest at mouse down, change  X-Y path or path intersection

Comment: Sure it's possible. I'm not sure the most elegant way to do this. My method would probably be a pretty clunky hack. I'd have an invisible grid add to the stage when the user presses the mouse button and then each cell in that grid would flip a Boolean value as you make your gesture with the mouse. Then, use some algorithm that determine if sufficiently correct cells were flipped to equate to an "x" or a "<" or what have you.  Now the symbols can be as complicated as you want but your grid will need to be of sufficient resolution. The more complex the input, the less allowable will be user err

Comment: I thought about this for a time, had a similar idea... I think, as that I just started and self teaching ( this is feeling like a bad idea, lol).. but, instead of a grid I am thinking of tracing the path. If the x value is static but the y value goes pos or neg it is a straight horizontal line... where the opposite would be vertical... but if both drifted the neg but the x value turns to pos it would be a < less than symbol... How might one track int value like this to activate a function?

Comment: That could work. But the more I try to think of how to make that work, the closer I come to just using a grid. Because you need some limits or allowable error for y drift that still accepts the input as horizontal line. And only if it drifts enough down does it count as an input of a diagonal line. So at that point you have made a grid mathematically.

Comment: But I haven't thought long and hard about it so take this all with a grain of salt.

Comment: oh  no, thanks it gave me food for thought... this is a direction and that is a tone more than I had before

Comment: I slept on what you were saying, but I am not sure as to how I would implement a literal grid to which Actionscript would understand the intersections... But if I lean on a proportion pixel movement (that not a real term, I am doof). Say the mouseDown is the origin and movement is tracked on 25 or 50 pixel basis... and ratio denote angularity... 30 degrees is a 2:1 and 90 degree 1:1... I am going to think this over

Comment: I'm just going to throw it out there as a possibility, don't know how well it would work with scaling considered. Have a bunch of bitmaps ready that define valid gestures. Let the player draw on an an invisible bitmap that is on top of the game. Use [BitmapData.compare](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29) to compare the drawn bitmap against your defined ones. The result of the function will tell you how much different the pictures are. Define a treshhold value (try and error) and check against it.

Comment: It isn't the most efficient approach and certainly not the fastest, but I think it would be easier(read:faster) than to train a Gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a gesture recognizer like [$1 Recognizer](http://depts.washington.edu/madlab/proj/dollar/). There is a [Flash example](http://www.betriebsraum.de/blog/2009/07/21/efficient-gesture-recognition-and-corner-finding-in-as3/) with source code linked from the project page.

Once you get it working you can train it to recognize whatever gestures you want to use in your game.

This works really well, because the gestures can be recognized even if they are drawn at a different scale or rotation than the original.